# sql for sliding rate card for charges

Tags: sql

I have a *sliding* (pro rata) rate card from which I need to charge customers, I'm wondering about the best design. For example, my rate card is something like this:

(Usage is an integer not a float).

```
Level    Usage    Rate
----------------------
0        10,000   $2.00
0        20,000   $1.00
0        30,000   $0.50
1        10,000   $4.00
1        20,000   $2.00
1        30,000   $1.00
```

So for example if the customer is at Level 0 using 15,000 widgets, they get charged:

```
10,000 * 2.00 = $20,000
 5,000 * 1.00 = $ 5,000
-----------------------
Total:          $25,000
```

**Notice** that the customer gets charged at $2.00/widget for the widgets between 1-10,000, then at $1.00/widget for the widgets between 10,001-20,000, and so on. That is, they *don't* get charged at the cheapest rate for all widgets - the 'earlier' widgets are more expensive, then the widgets get cheaper in greater quantites.

I was thinking of *pre-calculating* the charges, so then I could do a join between customer and calculated rates. Obviously, the table **pre_calc** would be large, but disk space is cheap. And it would be faster/easier than calculating the costs every time.

```
Table pre_calc
==============

Level    Usage    Cost
----------------------
0            0    $0
0            1    $2.00
0            2    $4.00
... etc
1            0    $0
1            1    $4.00
1            2    $8.00
... etc
```

Allowing me to do

```
SELECT c.name, p.cost
FROM customers as c
INNER JOIN pre_calc as p
ON c.level = p.level AND c.usage = p.usage;
```

Any comments on this design? Any better ways to do it?

Comment: It all depend on what are the queries that will be run against the database. If you will constantly calculating the costs, then it makes sense to have them already there to use.

Comment: Your solution should work fine, however you would need to recalculate the costs every time the first table changes, or if the potential bounds on order quantities increases (which may not be an issue, depending on the requirements of your application). However, this problem could be handled relatively easily and efficiently by loading the first table into a data structure within your application, and performing the necessary calculations there. SQL can do many things well, but some tasks can be more efficiently handled elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks guys. The rates card is static (changes about once a year), so no problems there. I could do the calcs in a middle tier, but it would be easier to do in the db as it will be accessed from multiple apps.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
level low     high       price

0     0       10000      20000
0     10000   20000      10000
0     20000   30000      5000
```

And then SQL:

```
select sum(p) from (
  select case 
    when $value$ > high 
      then price 
      else ($value$ - low) / (high - low) * price 
    end as p
  from ...
  where $value$ < high
)
```

Comment: I think you are in the right direction but if all rows have ``value < high`` (in the where clause) then the case will always go to the else, right?

Answer (score 1):

This query should work with your existing table structure. It's a bit more complicated than the pre-calculated query but, on the other hand, it doesn't use a pre-calculated table that needs to be updated for every usage int value when rates change. My guess is that the performance here will be worse than if you pre-calculate it, but you will only know for sure if you test it.

```
SELECT c.name,
    -- The usage rates less than or equal to the customer's usage
    (SELECT SUM(r.Rate * r.Usage)
     FROM Rates r 
     WHERE r.Level = c.Level and r.Usage <= c.Usage) +
    -- The rate from the usage rate immediately above the customer's level
    -- using the usage top limit from the rate immediately less or equal to the customer's usage
    (SELECT TOP 1 r2.Rate * (c.Usage - (SELECT TOP 1 r3.Usage FROM Rates r3 
                                        WHERE r3.Level = c.Level and r3.Usage <= c.Usage
                                        ORDER BY Usage DESC))
     FROM Rates r2
     WHERE r2.Level = c.Level and r2.Usage > c.Usage
     ORDER BY Usage ASC) as cost
FROM customers as c
```